# Close form when on time fixed C#

Tags: forms, fclose

I have a trouble with my form.
When my fo already open in a short time. I would like the form will auto close on time i fixed
Example: i opened that form at 7h40 and form will auto close at 8h10 every day.

I am using timer_tick but it is not working

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: It will be easier to answer if you show your code